In azure pipeline completion trigger, how to set default branch for depends pipeline via yaml
I want to trigger pipeline B automatically on completion of pipeline A.
For this, I have added 'resource pipeline' in pipeline B repo branch release/test.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: myproject.myprogram
    source: XXXXXXXX

But pipeline B is not triggered, as the default branch of B is main, not release/test.
To change this default branch, I have to edit pipeline triggers in UI.
I dont want UI intervention, can I set it via yaml?
I tried UI way, and it worked but now I need it via yaml

You might need to add the YAML pipeline source code to all relevant branches. See Branch considerations. See also Branch filters.

@RuiJarimba I can change the 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' manually through UI, but I want to change it through yaml or if I can set target branch of pipeline B to run.


To change this default branch, I have to edit pipeline triggers in UI. I don't want UI intervention, can I set it via yaml?

To change the pipeline default branch for an existing pipeline, you can only change it by edit pipeline triggers in UI.
By default, a pipeline's default branch is the default branch of the repository.
So, to set up a new pipeline with a different default branch, you can first change the repository's default branch.  Following this change, any new YAML pipeline you create will use this newly established default branch.

For more details of the branch usage in pipeline resource triggers, please refer Branch considerations

It appears that the function to change the default branch through yaml does not exist currently. You can also request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better. Engineers usually prioritize features that are urgent or have more votes.

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

Take a look at this example - this is placed after the name you put at the beginning of the pipeline - it tells the pipeline when to run itself.
The branch name that triggers the pipeline is 'main' in this case. If you add other branch names it will work too.

There is no any available option in YAML file to change the default ref of the pipeline run triggered by resource triggers.
As a workaround, you can try to use the REST API "Runs - Run Pipeline" to trigger pipelineB on the specified ref (e.g., refs/heads/release/test):

Add an intermediary pipeline that is triggered on completion of pipelineA. In this intermediary pipeline, add a step to call the API "Runs - Run Pipeline" to trigger pipelineB on the specified ref.

# azure-pipelines.yml of the intermediary pipeline.

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeA
    source: pipelineA
    trigger: true

steps:
- checkout: none
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Trigger PipelineB'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $organization = "organization-name"
      $project = "project-name"
      $pipelineId = 123
      $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/pipelines/${pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.0"

      $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
      }

      $body = @{
        resources = @{
          repositories = @{
            self = @{
              refName = "refs/heads/release/test"
            }
          }
        }
      } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

      Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body


In pipelineB, do not enabled trigger on the resource of pipelineA. You just need to remove the trigger section from the resource.

# azure-pipelines.yml of pipelineB.

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeA
    source: pipelineA

. . .

With this way:

When pipelineA is successfully completed, the intermediary pipeline gets triggered automatically.

The intermediary pipeline call the API "Runs - Run Pipeline" to trigger pipelineB on the ref "refs/heads/release/test".

The triggered run of pipelineB will use the latest successfully completed run of pipelineA as the resource.




Thanks for your response. Actually my scenario is I have dummy pipeline A after whose completion, all my microservices pipelines should get triggered. So microservices can be any number, due to which it is not convenient to put all its Uri in Powershell script.
